# optimized way to get values from list when list of indices given

Tags: python, list, loops

I have long list(`nextWordIndices`) of indices size of 7000. I want to get value list from another list to mach that indices. I can do this but it take lots of time

```
nextWord = []

for i in nextWordIndices:
    nextWord.append(allWords[i])
```

is there any optimize way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the indices are frequently the same, you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
word_getter = operator.itemgetter(*nextWordIndices)
nextWord = word_getter(allWords)
```

If you can use `word_getter` multiple times, and `tuple`s are OK for output, you might see a speed-up compared to a list-comprehension.

Timings:

```
python -m timeit -s "allWords = range(7000); nextWordIndices = range(7000)" "[allWords[i] for i in nextWordIndices]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 415 usec per loop
python -m timeit -s "allWords = range(7000); nextWordIndices = range(7000)" "map(allWords.__getitem__, nextWordIndices)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 614 usec per loop
python -m timeit -s "allWords = range(7000); nextWordIndices = range(7000); from operator import itemgetter" "itemgetter(*nextWordIndices)(allWords)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 292 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comp:

```
nextWord = [allWords[i] for i in nextWordIndices]
```

<s>Actually this might be faster</s> (will have to `timeit`)

```
map(allWords.__getitem__, nextWordIndices)
```

Comment: It'll definitely be faster on python3.x ;-)

Comment: @Darshana No, I removed that. That was most likely a typo

Answer (score 0):

Use map instead of loop.

```
def getWord(i):
    return allWords[i]

nextWord = map(getWord, nextWordIndices)
```